# Error when using @runInSeparateProcess with markTestSkipped()

Tags: phpunit

```
 /**
  * Tests Response->redirect
  * @runInSeparateProcess
 */
 public function testRedirect() {

    $this->markTestSkipped();
 }
```

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

```
There was 1 error:

1) ResponseTest::testRedirect

PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances' in -:44

Stack trace:
0 [internal function]: PDO->__sleep()

1 -(44): serialize(Array)

2 -(332): __phpunit_run_isolated_test()

3 {main}
  thrown in - on line 44

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances' in -:44

Stack trace:
0 [internal function]: PDO->__sleep()

1 -(44): serialize(Array)

2 -(332): __phpunit_run_isolated_test()

3 {main}
  thrown in - on line 44
```

Answer (score 1):

When PHPUnit goes to run a test in another process it will serialize a bunch of different data to give to that new process. I will assume you have a database connection hanging around in a variable which PHPUnit is trying to serialize.

Answer (score 0):

as @SamHennessy Mentioned , this issues is because of huge data in the stack trace when failures

This is because of a large Objects saved in the TestCase,

when there is a assertion failures , the trace is generated and serialized ,
so serialization breaks if there is huge data in traces.

in my case i was saving dataset in the test case , which generated a 239555 bytes of data in trace